# Why doesn't df's output default to a human-readable format?

Tags: disk-usage

I mean, did the developers think people would enjoy reading 19478204 rather than 19 GB?

Could it be that in the older systems there weren't as much disk space so it was OK back then to count each digit?

Comment: It's probably not accurate to think that measuring it in such small denominations was because volumes were smaller. It's more reasonable to assume that when `df` was first created, the main problem it was trying to solve was just getting a brief summary of disk usage _somehow_. So people at the time were more concerned with there just being _some_ number available to work with. `-h` was probably added later for people who didn't want to do the math each time but when adding new options you should keep default behavior, so they left it at printing blocks.

Comment: Backwards incompatible. Don't you care about breaking existing code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is more precise to output the byte count rather than the human readable numbers. I use both, but when copying data or verifying file sizes, non-human readable is a must.

Since one person's sensible default is another's constant annoyance, there's really no 'right' or 'wrong' answer. However, it is easy to force `df` to output human readable numbers:

```
$ echo "alias df='df -h'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

If you ever want to use `df` in its default mode, escape it with a `\` like this:

```
$ \df
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm just guessing, but most Unix tools are built to work in pipelines.  Viewed that way the number of bytes is probably the most useful, and thus a sensible default

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: because hard drives are in blocks of (mostly) 512 or some other power of 2

If you divide output of `df -k` (which is the default of GNU df version) by 1024 you actually get `df -h`.From reading [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Df_%28Unix%29) as well as man page on my Ubuntu system for `df`, it appears that there is a historical reason for it, as Unix System V was consistently using 512 size blocks. In fact, [disks sectors are made to hold 512MB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector), so I guess this is practical in the sense of understanding how many sectors of the disk space your partition takes up.

On the other hand, 1024 blocks is closer to what we understand as 1000 bytes, hence GNU probably made df output that by default. But again, while we humans think in bytes that are powers of 10, disks are created in sectors and computers speak in powers of 2^x.